# Windows Phone update: "Some settings are managed by your organisation"

Tags: windows-10-mobile, update

A friend of mine has an update but can't install it because of this message "some settings are managed by your organisation".

[image]

How can this be fixed without a reset to factory settings?

(I don't have the device with me, nor do I know the model or OS version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a reset factory setting can helps you. I had the same issue on NL1020 then on a NL930.
Sorry about that.

Comment: sorry but this is a no go... pffft

Comment: Resetting the phone is not an advisable for organizational account attached Windows Phones.

Comment: Sure that's not cool, but when a windows phone is bugged, this is the best ( and often only ) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Group Policies applied by the organisation to which the phone is connected.

Ask the Group Policy Administrator to apply a special group policy for your phone that will enable it to update Windows.